# I found a memoization code snippet, and I'm wondering how it would behave under copy.copy

Tags: python, decorator, memoization

I found this nice memoizing decorator:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize

The particular application is in artificial intelligence, and it will live inside an immutable state class. The trouble is that I perform application of operators by returning a copy.copy of the parent state, with requested operator applied. The copy.copy saves a lot of time that would otherwise be wasted, since most of the state is identical to its parent.

Now, here is my problem. If I were to use the above memoization class within the class, would the memoized copies of the functions, which memoize to potentially invalid values, be passed along? I presume I would need to invalidate the memoized copy somehow.

Comment: When you tried it, what did you find?

Comment: I didn't try it because my understanding of it is so limited and unless it behaved *exactly* how I anticipated, I wouldn't have had any idea now to interpret it.

Comment: You can use `print` statements to see what's going on, you know?  If you don't start adding print statements and experimenting, your pace of learning is going to be very, very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `copy.copy` is shallow, so it just copies a reference to the memoizing wrapper object. You can try it out like this if you remove the `__get__` method of `memoized` (otherwise, you'd get a `partial` object that's used to support bound methods):

```
class C(object):
    @memoized
    def foo(): pass

o1 = C()
o2 = copy.copy(o1)
print o1.foo.cache is o2.foo.cache
```

You can construct a new wrapper when needed (i.e. when you copy): `memoized(C.foo.func)`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, copying an object should create an exact clone: if there it has cached values, they should be copied too.  If this isn't done, it's generally as a speed optimization for deep copies and shouldn't have visible side-effects.

If you're making a copy of something and you want cached values in the copy to be cleared, then you should clear the cache explicitly.

If you really want copies of an object to not copy a cache, then define the `__copy__` or `__deepcopy__` methods to control copying.  (Note that the normal use of this is for copying underlying resources, like file descriptors and handles.)  I don't recommend doing this.

Here's an example of both.

```
class memoized(object):
    """
    Decorator that caches a function's return value each time it is called.
    If called later with the same arguments, the cached value is returned, and
    not re-evaluated.
    """
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.cache = {}
    def __copy__(self):
        """
        Don't copy the cache in a copy.
        """
        return memoized(self.func)
    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        """
        Don't copy the cache in a deep copy.
        """
        return memoized(self.func)

    def __call__(self, *args):
       try:
           return self.cache[args]
       except KeyError:
           value = self.func(*args)
           self.cache[args] = value
           return value
       except TypeError:
           # uncachable -- for instance, passing a list as an argument.
           # Better to not cache than to blow up entirely.
           return self.func(*args)
    def __repr__(self):
        """Return the function's docstring."""
        return self.func.__doc__
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        """Support instance methods."""
        return functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)
    def clear_cache(self):
        self.cache = {}

@memoized
def fibonacci(n):
    "Return the nth fibonacci number."
    if n in (0, 1):
        return n
    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

fibonacci(12)
print fibonacci.cache
fibonacci.clear_cache()
print fibonacci.cache

fibonacci(12)
print fibonacci.cache
import copy
f = copy.deepcopy(fibonacci)
print f.cache
```

Comment: As a side-note, remember that copy.copy is a shallow copy, not copying the internal properties (eg. the copy doesn't copy the cache of the original function; it uses the *same* cache dictionary), and copy.deepcopy makes a copy of everything, which you probably don't want either if this is an optimization.  You probably want some properties to be deep copies and some to be shallow copies.

Comment: Wait a minute. Look at the __call__ function of the memoize decorator class. The arguments include *args. Therefore, if I decorate an instance method with this, wouldn't it result in a different entry because the self parameter in *args would point to a different argument set? This would cause hell with memory and garbage collection, but it would work...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  I only used the code you linked to and modified it to demonstrate how to use `__copy__` and `__deepcopy__`.